# Getting the Travis CI build status of a GitHub commit

Tags: github, github-api, status, travis-ci-api

### Question

How would one get the build status of Travis CI of a particular GitHub commit from the of any arbitrary open source project?

### Example

For example, how would an arbitrary GitHub user (with a Travis account) query the passing/failed build status of [this build](https://travis-ci.com/github/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/builds/211162054) based on the following information:

- username: `a-t-0`
- repository: `Code-LatexReportTemplate`
- branch: `main`
- Commit: `2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda`

### Attempts

To get the status of that commit I tried:

1. A get command:

```
GET /repos/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/commits/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda/status
```

Which returns nothing.

2. A curl command:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/commits/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda/status
```

Which returns a lot of information, but an [empty statuses](https://api.github.com/repos/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/statuses/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda) information as shown in the selected output below:

```
 "state": "pending",
  "statuses": [

  ],
```

This empty statuses information seems to be contradictory to [the green checkflag](https://github.com/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/commit/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda) on that commit, which shows [the build on that commit](https://github.com/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/runs/1621796954) is [passed](https://travis-ci.com/github/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/builds/211162054).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [check-run api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#runs) using Github API rest v3 like this

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repo]/commits/[hash]/check-runs
```

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/commits/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda/check-runs

and for [check-suites](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#check-suites) :

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repo]/commits/[hash]/check-suites
```

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/commits/2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda/check-suites

Using [graphql API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), you can use `statusCheckRollup` field :

```json
query {
  repository(name: "Code-LatexReportTemplate", owner:"a-t-0"){
    object(oid: "2758dc700dfaa9726f0e1755753347b4d450acda") {
      ... on Commit {
        message
        statusCheckRollup {
          state
          contexts(first: 100) {
            nodes {
              __typename
              ... on CheckRun {
                name
                detailsUrl
                completedAt
                status
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "object": {
        "message": "Removed another unneeded file.",
        "statusCheckRollup": {
          "state": "SUCCESS",
          "contexts": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "__typename": "CheckRun",
                "name": "Travis CI - Branch",
                "detailsUrl": "https://travis-ci.com/github/a-t-0/Code-LatexReportTemplate/builds/211162054",
                "completedAt": "2020-12-29T13:12:26Z",
                "status": "COMPLETED"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Checkout [statuscheckrollupcontext](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/unions#statuscheckrollupcontext) and [checkrun](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#checkrun)